# Usage of Android managed configurations with react-native

Tags: react-native

is it possible to create a Android (work) app with [managed configuration](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations) with react-native?

Thanks

Comment: help your readers by telling what you have tried or researched achieving your goal, and why (possibly) that didn't help you